# How does one show that the free compact boson CFT is rational when the radius squared is a rational number?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

In [Rational Conformal Field Theories and Complex Multiplication](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0203213) by Gukov and Vafa, they briefly mention that the conformal field theory (CFT) describing a free bosonic field on a circle of radius $R$ is a rational CFT whenever $R^2$ is rational.

More precisely, on page 5, they explain that whenever
$$
R^2=\frac{k}{l}, ~~ k,l\in\mathbb{Z},
$$
the partition function given on page 3,
$$
Z(q,\overline{q},R)=\frac{1}{|\eta|^2}\sum_{(p,\overline{p})\in\Gamma^{1,1}}q^{\frac{1}{2}p^2}\overline{q}^{\frac{1}{2}\overline{p}^2}
$$
takes the form
\begin{equation}
Z(q,\overline{q})=\sum_{i+j=0~ mod ~2k\\i-j=0~ mod ~2l}\chi_i(q)\overline{\chi}_j(\overline{q}),
\end{equation}
where $\chi_i(q)=\textrm{tr}_{V_i}q^{L_0-\frac{c}{24}}$ are holomorphic characters.
My question is, how does one show this?
It is straightforward, from the definition of the momenta, that
$$
p^2=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{n^2}{k/l}+nm+m^2\frac{k}{l})
$$
and
$$
\overline{p}^2=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{n^2}{k/l}-nm+m^2\frac{k}{l}).
$$

But it is not clear to me how the partition function subsequently factorizes.